# Can view email in outlook but not on iPhone, Mime-attachment

Tags: email, iphone

Hi can anyone tell me why emails originating from one company cannot be viewed on our companies iPhones / iPads but can be viewed in Outlook it shows the following screen:

[image]

In Outlook the message body will appear just fine.

Hope somebody can help.